# Printing an array of arrays from value input in html table

Tags: html, arrays, for-loop, printing, html-table

I am trying to print a 2-d array that i get from an http request to the variable value using this code

```html
<table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th> 
                <th>School</th>
            </tr>
            <script>
            var x ="", i;
            var y ="", j;
            for (i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
                x ="<tr>" + 
                for (j=0; j<3; j++){
                    y = "<td>" + {{ value[i][j] }} + "</td>";
                }
                + "</tr>";
            }
            </script>
</table>
```

Any ideas why it isn't working? :P

Answer (score 0):

Tag `<script>` not displayed in any way, you need to use [JavaScript methods for DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents)

```js
const values = [
    ["name1", "age1", "school1"],
    ["name2", "age2", "school2"],
];
const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    const fields = values[i];

    for (let j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
        const field = fields[j];
        const td = document.createElement("td");

        td.textContent = field;

        tr.appendChild(td);
    }

    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>School</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: values cannot be const as it changes every time an http request is send, also where does the code goes so it reruns every time the variable value change?

Comment: i tried putting it after the code that i acquire the value variable so it runs every time an http response arrive, but still nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate string with a for loop. You cannot do that. Also, declare i and j variables inside the for loop so they are automatically removed when the loop is done. You do not need the y variable because you can create a long string as x and then use it as innerHTML somewhere. Lastly, the value array was incorrectly used. {} is used to create an object. For example var b = {}; When you want to actually use the object, you refer to it by its name, but you said you have an array already.

```
    <script>
    var x ="";
    for (var i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
        x +="<tr>"; 
        for (var j=0; j<value[i].length; j++){
            x += "<td>" + value[i][j] + "</td>";
        }
        x += "</tr>";
    }
    //use your output x variable here
    </script>
```

Comment: i tried it but nothing, the value is sent alright but it is not displayed

Comment: How are you using the x variable? I wasnt sure what you want to do with it so I just put a comment there.

Comment: when i receive the varible value i want to print it in an html table, which means that the table will change every time the variable changes